# Knockout validation alway show default error when I use error template

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using validation knockout for my project
And i used template for all error messages:

```
    <script type="text/html" id="errorTemplate">
        <div class="errorContainer error_bottom" data-bind="visible: field.isModified() && !field.isValid()">
        <div class="error_arrow">
        <div class="error_arrow_inner"></div>            
        </div>
        <span class="error" data-bind="text: field.error"></span>
        </div>
    </script>

<script>
    // KO validastor setup:
    ko.validation.configure({
        decorateElement: true,
        errorElementClass: 'error', // Add class to input
        registerExtenders: true,
        messagesOnModified: true,
        insertMessages: true,
        parseInputAttributes: true,
        messageTemplate: 'errorTemplate' // Use template 
    });

    function ReservationViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.email = ko.observable("");
            self.name = ko.observable("");
            self.phone = ko.observable("");

            var validator = ko.validatedObservable({
                email: self.email.extend({required: true, email: true}),
                name: self.name.extend({required: true}),
                phone: self.phone.extend({required: true}),
            });
    // continues ...
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ReservationViewModel());
</script>
```

But It alway get default message: "This field is required." for custom error or email is not valid.
Can u help me fix it?
Thanks all.

Comment: Adding your view model code would probably help people answer your question.

Comment: I added my view model

Comment: I get the same problem, can anyone help?